# Numpy matrix(array) rationale

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I am so confused about Numpy array. Let's say I have two Numpy arrays.

```
a = np.array([[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]])
b = np.array([[1,10], [1, 10]])
```

My interpretations of `a` and `b` are 3x2 and 2x2 matrices, i.e,

```
a = 1 2    b = 1 10
    3 4        1 10
    5 6
```

Then, I thought it should be fine to do `a * b` since it is a multiplication of 3x2 and 2x2 matrices. However, it was not possible and I had to use `a.dot(b)`.

Given this fact, I think my intepretation of Numpy array is not right. Can anyone let me know how I should think of Numpy array? I know that I can do `a*b` if I convert `a` and `b` into np.matrix. However, looking at other's code, it seems that people are just fine to use Numpy array as matrix, so I wonder how I should understand Numpy array in terms of matrix.

Comment: If you are on Python 3.5, you can use `a @ b` to do what you want.  `a * b` does an _elementwise_ multiplication.

Comment: Also, to check if you're dimensions match, you can try `.shape` to see the dimensions. Then, if you find out that the dimensions don't match, you can transpose it. :)

Comment: Both kinds of multiplicatin are useful.  Look at MATLAB code, you'll see both `a*b` and `a.*b`.

Comment: Why does having to use `.dot` bother you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For numpy arrays, the `*` operator is used for element by element multiplication of arrays. This is only well defined if both arrays have the same dimensions. To illuminate `*`-multiplication, note that element by element multiplication with the identity matrix will not return the same matrix

```
>>> I = np.array([[1,0],[0,1]])
>>> B = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
>>> I*B
array([[ 1, 0], 
       [ 0, 4]])
```

Using the numpy function `dot(a,b)` produces the typical matrix multiplication.

```
>>> dot(I,B)
array([[ 1, 2],
       [ 3, 4]])
```

Comment: How is there a 10 on your result (I*B) 2nd column, 2nd line?

Comment: Thanks for the catch! I accidentally copied and pasted the wrong multiplication from my terminal. Error corrected above.

Answer (score 1):

`np.dot` is probably what you're looking for?

```
a = np.array([[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]])

b = np.array([[1,10], [1, 10]])

np.dot(a,b)

Out[6]:
array([[  3,  30],
       [  7,  70],
       [ 11, 110]])
```